# Linked List Calc only evaluates 1st number. c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, postfix-notation

I am working on a postfix calculator and I am very close to finishing but I am stumped on why my calculator is only evaluating the 1st input. For example, if I enter: "1 2 3 ++" it only pops the first number and displays "1" as the answer. I feel like this problem stems from the main loop where the numbers being entered and passed to the stack are not being pushed correctly. Any suggestions/tips are appreciated! Thanks!

```
class Dstack
{

    public:
        Dstack();
        ~Dstack();
        void push(double value);
        bool pop(double &value);
        int size();
        bool empty();
        int top();

    private:

        class Node
        {
            public:
                Node(double value, Node *next)
                {m_value = value; m_next = next;}
                double m_value;
                Node *m_next;
        };
        Node *m_head;


};

Dstack::Dstack()
{
    m_head = NULL;
}

Dstack::~Dstack()
{
    Node *ptr = m_head;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        Node *temp;

        temp = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->m_next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void Dstack::push(double value)
{
    m_head = new Node(value, m_head);
}

bool Dstack::pop(double &value)
{
    //Node *ptr = m_head;
    if(m_head == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
            Node *temp = m_head;
            value = m_head->m_value;
            m_head = m_head->m_next;
            delete temp;
            return true;
    }
}

int Dstack::size()
{
    int num_elements = 0;

    Node *ptr = m_head;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        num_elements++;
        ptr = ptr->m_next;
    }
    return num_elements;
}

bool Dstack::empty()
{
    if(m_head == NULL)
        return true;

    else
        return false;

}

//main

void error()
{
    cerr << "Illegal" << endl;
    exit(1);
}


int main()
{
    double lVal, rVal, answer;
    Dstack stack;
    double num;


    while((cin.peek()) != -1)
    {
        if(cin.peek() >= 'a' && cin.peek() <= 'z')
        {
            error();
        }
        if(isspace(cin.peek()))
        {
            cin.ignore();
            break;
        }
        if(isdigit(cin.peek()) || cin.peek() == '.')
           {
               cin >> num;
               if(cin.good())
               {
                    stack.push(num);
               }
           }
        else if(cin.peek() == '+')
        {
            rVal = stack.pop(num);
            lVal = stack.pop(num);
            answer = rVal + lVal;
            stack.push(answer);
            break;
        }
        else if(cin.peek() == '-')
        {
            rVal = stack.pop(num);
            lVal = stack.pop(num);
            answer = rVal - lVal;
            stack.push(answer);
            break;
        }
        else if(cin.peek() == '*')
        {
            rVal = stack.pop(num);
            lVal = stack.pop(num);
            answer = rVal * lVal;
            stack.push(answer);
            break;
        }
        else if(cin.peek() == '/')
        {
            rVal = stack.pop(num);
            lVal = stack.pop(num);
            answer = rVal / lVal;
            stack.push(answer);
            break;
        }
        else if(cin.peek() == '^')
        {
            rVal = stack.pop(num);
            lVal = stack.pop(num);
            answer = pow(rVal, lVal);
            stack.push(answer);
            break;
        }
        stack.pop(answer);
    }

    cout << "\nAnswer: " << answer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program `break`s after reading the first space, which ends the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried taking out the breaks before and it would give me an endless input where I could not even use ^D to exit. Any way around this?

Comment: Having a closer look at your code there's no way any of this will do what you want it to, take `rVal = stack.pop(num)` for instance, the value is popped into `num`, not returned by the function (which just returns a `bool`). I suggest you fix your logic first before working about program flow.

Comment: What you have said makes sense but I am unsure of how to solve it from here. How would you suggest I fix this and implement a system that can evaluate the top two numbers in the stack? Thanks

Comment: `stack.pop(rval);` I guess.